# Animating TripsLayer in deck.gl with python

Tags: python, gis, deck.gl

I have seen the TripsLayer example in the deck.gl website ([this one](https://deck.gl/examples/trips-layer/)) and it looks really cool. I would like to accomplish the same but using pydeck, the python bindings for deck.gl. The example in pydeck's webpage ([this one](https://pydeck.gl/gallery/trips_layer.html)) is not animated and I am not sure how should I do it to get a smooth animation as shown in the javascript example. I have tried multiple things (passing lists, functions, variables with changing value etc.) but non of them have worked and I can't find any example with pydeck.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's true that the example should include more trips. Here is how to achieve the animation of multiple trips in a jupyter notebook.

```
import time
import pandas as pd
import pydeck as pdk

data = '[{"agent_id":0,"path":[[-0.63968,50.83091,0.0],[-0.78175,50.83205,0.0]],"time":[65100,65520],"color":[228,87,86]},{"agent_id":1,"path":[[-0.63968,50.83091,0.0],[-0.78175,50.83205,0.0]],"time":[65940,66420],"color":[178,121,162]},{"agent_id":2,"path":[[-0.63968,50.83091,0.0],[-0.37617,50.8185,0.0]],"time":[65340,66360],"color":[157,117,93]},{"agent_id":3,"path":[[-0.63968,50.83091,0.0],[-0.78175,50.83205,0.0]],"time":[65940,66420],"color":[238,202,59]},{"agent_id":4,"path":[[-0.63968,50.83091,0.0],[-0.78175,50.83205,0.0]],"time":[67740,68160],"color":[157,117,93]}]'

df = pd.read_json(data)
view = {"bearing": 0, "latitude": 50.85, "longitude": -0.16, "pitch": 0, "zoom": 9}

time_min = 65_000
time_max = 80_000

layer = pdk.Layer(
    "TripsLayer",
    df,
    get_path='path',
    get_timestamps='time',
    get_color='color',
    opacity=0.8,
    width_min_pixels=3,
    rounded=True,
    trail_length=900,
    current_time=0
)

# Render
r = pdk.Deck(layers=[layer], initial_view_state=view, map_style='dark_no_labels')

r.show()

# Animate
for ct in range(time_min, time_max, 100):
    layer.current_time = ct
    r.update()
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: I just used the same code in my pydeck and it just shows the basemap

Comment: This example code doesn't work currently as of Nov 2023.